# Order by in Lotus Notes formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

Is is possible to query those documents from a Lotus Domino database which have bigger universal ID than a given number/ID and order them by their universal ID with a Lotus formula query? If yes, how?

In SQL the following is similar to what I'd like to:

```
SELECT universalId 
FROM all_documents
WHERE universalId > custom_value
ORDER BY universalId
```

Comment: Why do you want to know which documents have 'bigger' universal IDs? Are you trying to find a collection of new documents? Universal IDs are not issued sequentially, so a 'bigger' UNID may not represent a more recent document.

Comment: @DavidNavarre: I'd like iterate over every document in a database and be able to continue it from the last one if the processing breaks (network connection error etc.). I guess I should ask this as a new questions.

Comment: @DavidNavarre: Full story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020620/iterating-over-every-document-in-lotus-domino

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
SELECT @Text(@DocumentUniqueId) > custom_value
```

This will work in a view selection formula. If you also make the formula for the first column of the view `@Text(@DocumentUniqueId)`, and set the sort property for the view, then you have the equivalent of `ORDER BY`.

The selection formula will also work in a `NotesDatabase.Search()` call in LotusScript or COM, or a `Database.Search()` call in Java.  That will give you a `NotesDocumentCollection` (or `DocumentCollection` in Java), and you can write code to sort it.

NOTE: The `search()` method will be  will be quite inefficient in large databases.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late answer. The filtering works well, I've just need to put the universal ID between two `'`s. I couldn't try the view since I don't have write permissions to the database.